# How to get continuous index for the visible elements in angular and ignore the indexing of the hidden elements *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 angular components for displaying the list of approved pharmacies and new pharmacies respectively. I only have an array of pharmacies and I want to display the list of the approved pharmacies based on the status(ie whether approved or not) field of the pharmacy objects. Status field is of type boolean.If status field is true, the pharmacy object will be displayed in the list of the approved pharmacies otherwise it'll be hidden.The problem is I want get continuous index for visible elements and avoid indexing of the hidden elements.
approvedPharmacies.html

```
 <tr  *ngFor="let pharmacy of newPharmacys;let i=index" >
        <ng-container *ngIf="pharmacy.status==false">
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)>{{pharmacy.createdOn}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)>{{pharmacy.name}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy) >{{pharmacy.location}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)>{{pharmacy.email}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)>{{pharmacy.contact}}</td>
        <td (click)=navigateToPharmacy(pharmacy)><button type="button" class="btn btn-square btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="deleteFromDisabled(pharmacy)" (click)="addToEnabled(pharmacy)">approve</button></td>
        <td><label class="toggle-switch arya-3d toggle-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-input">
            <span class="toggle-slider"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
```

Here I want to avoid indexing of the hidden elements.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be good decision to do manipulations inside template. Template is used to display the content and we should avoid data manipulation inside template (HTML).

It would be better if you filter your dataset inside the component class and show only the required data. With this you can efficiently perform manipualtions. It will be scalable as well if you want to perform more manipulations in future.

I have created a stackblitz instance for you here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhlfqm

Answer (score 0):

We can make it very simply.
Just create a function in component.ts file

```
getActiveDataFromNewPharmacys():Array<any> {
    // type of status must be boolean
    return this.newPharmacys.filter(obj => obj.status);
}
```

And call this function in the component.html file for looping like this.

```
<tr  *ngFor="let pharmacy of getActiveDataFromNewPharmacys();let i=index" >
```

then you will get only active products in html and take continuous index.

***Additional Info***
It is better to make create function more generic.

```
getActiveDataFromArrayList:Array<any>):Array<any> {
    // type of status must be boolean
    return arrayList.filter(obj => obj.status);
}
```

Then this function can reuse for any obj.. The first function is variable dependend.

Hope this will helpful for you

***..Happy coding..***